# ArrayAdapter not showing data in 2nd Activity

Tags: android

I am new to Android coding, I am trying to pass data from an Array to a ListView, I can get this to work on the first Activity in the App, but the second Activity is showing no data, can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

I have tried 6 or 7 examples from web searches but nothing works, creating a new app using the examples work, the only difference being I am I implementing the Array on the 2nd Activity

> public class StartPage extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_page);
>
>     Log.d("myTag", "This is my message1");
>    /* public void goToActivity2 (View view){
>         Intent intent = new Intent (this, BuildingSiteInfoActivity.class);
>         startActivity(intent);*/
>     }
>
>     public void openWindow2(View v) {
>         //call window2
>         setContentView(R.layout.building_site_info);
>         Log.d("myTag", "This is my message1.1");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> public class BuildingSiteInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
>
> ```
> ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
>
>
> // Array of strings...
> ListView simpleList;
> String animalList[] = {"Lion","Tiger","Monkey","Elephant","Dog","Cat","Camel"};
>
>
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.building_site_info);
>
>     List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
>     dataList.add("Java");
>     dataList.add("Android");
>     dataList.add("JavaEE");
>     dataList.add("JSP");
>     dataList.add("JDBC");
>
>
>     Log.d("myTag", "This is my message2");
>
>     simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
>     Log.d("myTag", "This is my message3");
>     ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_listview, R.id.textView,
> ```
>
> dataList);
>           simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
>           Log.d("myTag", "This is my message4");
>
> > 
>
> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imageView2"
>     android:layout_width="391dp"
>     android:layout_height="682dp"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>     app:srcCompat="@drawable/darkbluex" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView2"
>     android:layout_width="233dp"
>     android:layout_height="63dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
>     android:text="@string/bsText1"
>     android:textAlignment="center"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>     android:textSize="18sp"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView3"
>     android:layout_width="345dp"
>     android:layout_height="102dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
>     android:text="@string/bsText2"
>     android:textAlignment="center"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>     android:textSize="20sp"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
>
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/homePage1"
>     android:layout_width="299dp"
>     android:layout_height="97dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/buttonrec1"
>     android:text="Back"
>     android:textAlignment="center"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/simpleListView" />
>
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
>     android:layout_width="317dp"
>     android:layout_height="261dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
>     android:background="@android:color/white"
>     android:scrollbars="vertical"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
> <!--app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"-->
> ```
>
> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/textView"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center"
>     android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
>     android:textColor="@android:color/black"
>     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
>     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>      /> </LinearLayout>
> ```

The first Activity is the "StartPage" class, "This is my message1" & "This is my message1.1" are in the Logcat, the button assigned pushes to Activity2 "BuildingSiteInfoActivity" Class where the Array is implemented I have tried String to array "animalList" & "dataList" but I get an empty ListView & no other "This is my message" appear in the log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lawqf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey welcome to Android developers group

this code is wrong! its just load your layout;

```
//call window2
setContentView(R.layout.building_site_info);
//this is wrong
```

if you want to load your activity, you can use this:

```
//call window2
startActivity(new Intent(this , BuildingSiteInfoActivity.class));
//this is correct
```

in your code second activity does'nt run!
try it, I hope it works:)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, I have made the change but still there is no data in the ListView, with either lines of code the view loads but with an empty list view

Comment: I have uploaded a screen shot showing the view with empty ListView

Comment: Amazing Thank you, this has solved the problem, I added your new code in the wrong java file first, now all works great